Weird SwiftUI TextField Bug
I am currently working on a rather large project that spans many different files and uses SwiftData. It uses a Main View that holds a Navigation Stack as well as a TabView with a custom TabBar. This has worked so far. Now, one of the screens features a TextField. When I started developing this screen, I ran into the following Error Message.

Can't find or decode reasons Failed to get or decode unavailable
reasons Can't find or decode disabled use cases Can't find or decode
reasons Failed to get or decode unavailable reasons

This error message was accompanied by a rather long lag, that occurred when tapping the TextField for the first time. Once in the TextField, this error was thrown every time the keyboard was tapped / the TextField was exited or entered. The lag was gone after the first time.
Thinking that this error might have been caused by the animations I used, I removed them one by one. The problem stayed the same, however. I then started isolating the source of this problem (which turned out to be the TextField), eliminating every other possibility in the process (Removing the connection to SwiftData, Styling, etc.) In my confusion, I wrote up the following quick and easy View
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
            
            Text(username)
        }
    }
}

and put it into the Root of my App.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData


@main
struct K_TutorApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

This, however STILL THREW THE SAME ERROR!!!
I even uninstalled the app on my phone (I am using my phone as the simulator), and the error still persists.
Does anyone know what I could try to fix this / why this error occurs?

This didn´t throw an errror did it? It shows a warning in the xcode console. This is a known bug. apple forum

Not sure if related, but make sure your NavigationStack is inside the TabView, not the other way around.
